# A question about finitely generated $p$-groups

Tags: group-theory, p-groups

My question is about finitely generated $p$-groups.
In general, a subgroup of a finitely generated group is not necessarily finitely generated. But, my question is about finite and finitely generated $p$-groups. More specifically: if $G$ is a finitely generated $p$-group, say, $m$-generated and $U$ is a finitely generated subgroup of $G$, then is $U$ at most $m$-generated? If not, can $U$ be generated by a number of elements that depends only on $m$?

Comment: Is G finite? That's not 100% clear from the question.

Comment: I don't think this is true, take a maximal elementary abelian subgroup.

Comment: Yes, yatima2975. $G$ is finite.

Answer (score 3):

A wreath product of a cyclic group of order $p$ with a cyclic group of order $p^k$ is 2-generated, but the base group of the wreath product requires $p^k$ generators. So the answer to both questions is no.

Comment: Derek, this theorem M. Hall presented below is true? Do you have a copy of this book for me to read? For me it seems that if the theorem is true then the answer to my question would be true too! thank you

Comment: @AgenorAndrade DerekHolt's answer doesn't contradict Hall.  If a group is $k$ generated it's also $m$ generated for $m> k$.

Comment: Proving that a group of order $p^k$ can be generated by at most $k$ elements is easy. Just keep choosing elements that are not in the subgroup generated by the elements chosen so far, and use Lagrange's Theorem.